# PHP Symfony DQL - Too few parameters: the query defines 1 parameters but you only bound 0

Tags: php, symfony, dql, doctrine-query

i am trying to put together a SELECT in symfony repository project but for some reason getting error message in the subject. Been working on it for a few days but cannot find a solution with different variations of the code. This is the code

```
$qb3 = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$qb3-> select('check.userid')
    -> from('App\Entity\YY_Table', 'check')
    -> where('DATE_FORMAT(now(), \'%e-%b-%Y\') - DATE_FORMAT(check.datecreated, \'%e-%b-%Y\') <=360');

$qb2 = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$qb2-> select('((:numemails1 / COUNT(subs.id)) * 10)')
    -> from('App\Entity\XX_Table', 'subs')
    -> where($qb2->expr()->notIn('subs.id', $qb3->getDQL()))
    -> setParameter('numemails1', $numemails);
$rand_num = $qb2->getQuery()->getResult();

$qb1 = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$qb1-> select('subss.id')
    -> from('App\Entity\XX_Table', 'subss')
    -> where('RAND() < :sqbresult')
    -> orderBy('RAND()')
    -> setMaxResults($numemails)
    -> setParameter('sqbresult', $rand_num);

/*primary query to select users for future campaigns*/
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$qb -> select('s')
    -> from('App\Entity\XX_Table', 's')
    -> where($qb->expr()->In('s.id', $qb1->getDQL()));
    //-> where($expr->not($expr->exists($qb1->getDQL())));
return $qb ->getQuery() ->getResult();
```

and I am trying to get the alternative of .sql code below to select random entities from DB that passed some basic criteria

```
SELECT 
g.* FROM XX_table g
JOIN
    (SELECT 
         id
     FROM
         XX_table
     WHERE
         RAND() < (SELECT 
                    ((60000 / COUNT(*)) * 10) as rand_num
                   FROM
                    XX_table
                   WHERE 
                    id NOT IN (SELECT userID as id FROM YY_table emst WHERE CURDATE() - emst.datecreated <=360)
                  )
     ORDER BY RAND()
     LIMIT 60000) AS z ON z.id= g.id
```

I have checked answers on here:
[Too few parameters: the query defines 1 parameters but you only bound 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44412692/too-few-parameters-the-query-defines-1-parameters-but-you-only-bound-0)
and here
https://github.com/stwe/DatatablesBundle/issues/685
and feel like solution is somewhere close but cannot get to it

Comment: `$rand_num = $qb2->getQuery()->getResult();` will per default return an array of results. `getSingleResult()` Is maybe what you actually intended.

To help yourself, do a `dump($rand_num);` and see if that holds what you want as your query params

Comment: hello @b.enoit.be. I actually to need the array so this is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you need to actually call:

```
$qb->setParameter('sqbresult', $rand_num)
```

before the last line. In fact, there is no reason to call it on `$qb1`, as this will basically get discarded.

The reason for this is that, in your code above, you are basically just using `$qb1` as a DQL generation mechanism. Any parameters set on this are not passed on when the call to `getDQL` is made, only the string value of the DQL at that point.

If you were to `var_dump($qb->getDQL())` just before the end, you would see something like:

```
SELECT s FROM App\Entity\XX_Table s WHERE s.id IN (
         SELECT subss.id FROM App\Entity\XX_Table subss
                         WHERE RAND() < :sqbresult
                         ORDER BY RAND() ASC
)
```

showing that `:sqbresult` still remains in the DQL and thus needs to have a parameter set.